# ContextMenu MenuItems adding continuously on Click event

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

on click event ,I have return adding of menu items to contextmenu.but on clicking more than once it keeps adding the menu items to the contextmenu. Here the below code am using for it.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="13" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                    <Button  Name="btnMobile" Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0 0 20 0" Width="70"></Button>
                                    <!--<extToolkit:DropDownButton x:Name="ddBtnMobile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 30 0" Height="20"/>-->
                                    <Button   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ddBtnMobile" Width="30" Click="OnddBtnMobileClick"  Margin="0,0,0,5"  >
                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <Path x:Name="btnArrow3" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Fill="#FF527DB5" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                                        </Button.Content>
                                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu Name="cMenu">

                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
```

code am using is below

```
     private void OnddBtnMobileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    mnItem = new MenuItem();
                    mnItem.Header ="B1"; 
                    cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
                    mnItem = new MenuItem();
                    mnItem.Header ="A1";
                    cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
                    mnItem = new MenuItem();
                    mnItem.Header="B 2";
                    cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
 cMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMenuItemClick));
                }

  private void OnMenuItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    RoutedEventArgs args = e as RoutedEventArgs;
                    MenuItem item = args.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
                    string header = item.Header.ToString();
                    if (header == "Business")
                    {
                        btnMobile.Content = header;
                    }
                    else if (header == "Assistant")
                    {
                        btnMobile.Content = header;
                    }

                }
```

how to solve my issue.. Is there any better way of writing the above logic. i.e., adding menu items of context menu at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a boolean data member which will check if the sub menu's were already added

```
private void OnddBtnMobileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(alreadyAdded == true) 
      return;

   alreadyAdded = true;
   mnItem = new MenuItem();
   mnItem.Header ="B1"; 
   cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
   mnItem = new MenuItem();
   mnItem.Header ="A1";
   cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
   mnItem = new MenuItem();
   mnItem.Header="B 2";
   cMenu.Items.Add(mnItem);
   cMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnMenuItemClick));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...i have one more doubt...OnMenuItemClick event handler how can identify the particular btnmname...because i want to use the same method and event handler for 3 buttons..can u suggest me any idea ..to do this?

Comment: @kida the sender object is the button which got clicked, you can cast it to Button and check its name

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in the button click event's starting.

```
cMenu = new cMenu();
```

Thats you need to create a new instance.

Thanks,